# 127.0.0.1 refuse to connect 127.0.0.1:8080 works ok

Tags: apache, http, hyperlink

I have a local web that I run using Apache and Windows10 to manage and index my programs it has worked happily for years.  Two days ago I started to get a problem with my generated links where the links //127.0.0.1/ caused a "127.0.0.1 refused to connect error". I have trolled the internet for hours looking for a fix and have a workaround.

If I change my links from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1:8080 my links work.

Something happened to change the way my links were processed, I have fiddled with the httpd.conf and etc\hosts file but cannot get my original links of /127.0.0.1/ to work I have to add the :8080 for the port.

I would like to be able change something so that 127.0.0.1 works as it did for years without having to define 8080 in the link

**example links**

http://127.0.0.1/edsa-localweb/a_list_directories.php?target=html     #  127.0.0.1 refused to connect

the above link is programmatically generated and had worked without issues for YEARS

http://127.0.0.1:8080/edsa-localweb/a_list_directories.php?target=html    #  works a treat

same as above with :8080 added

Answer (score 0):

Well I was just demonstrating to a person how my links didn't work and now they do.  I find this particularly bizarre, I have been playing around with this problem for days my PC has been up and down, I have flushed things edited files, stopped and started HTTP server and had come up with my work around of of inserting :8080 into my link.

Most recently this morning my links were NOT working with :8080, a few hours pass my computer went to sleep I woke it up, went to demonstrate the links and the links now work without :8080.

I guess I am happy, I now don't have to do anything but I wish I understood what went wrong and how it managed to fix itself.

GREMLINS!